# How to use d3-jetpack with d3v4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I am trying to recreate this You Draw It graph:https://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/07d9040c3422dac16bd5be741433ff1e

It requires d3.conventions function which is in d3-jetpack which I found here: https://github.com/gka/d3-jetpack

raw d3v4 version is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gka/d3-jetpack/master/build/d3v4%2Bjetpack.js

^I saved this file in the same folder as my index.html.

How do I import it into my index.html for my project?

ATTEMPT 1

Here is what I tried:

```
<script>
var d3 = Object.assign({}, require('d3v4+jetpack.js'));
</script>
```

This is the error I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

ATTEMPT 2

Added `<script src="d3v4+jetpack.js"></script>` in the header of the html file.
Says d3.conventions still not found.

Comment: When you did Attempt 2, you aren't by chance sourcing the regular d3v4 js file after the +jetpack one?

Comment: Ah I was! Thank you so much! If you comment as the answer, I will upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to go down the `d3` *and* `jetpack` route together, as it seems to be the case by your references to `d3v4+jetpack.js`, you *must not* load vanilla `d3` in your script.

```
const d3j = require('d3-jetpack/build/d3v4+jetpack');
```

The line above does it for me. Note that it exposes `d3j` instead of `d3`, so you will of course need to adapt your code to something like:

```
const x = d3j.scaleLinear();
```

Hope this helps you!